# What is the best way to add comment in Visualforce Code

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-vf-component, comments

I am working on a existing VF code and added a comment like this, it appears on the page.

```
// Bla Bla Bla
```

I changed the comment to this, but receive the below error.

```
<! Bla Bla Bla>
```

> "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or
>   markup".

What is the proper syntax for adding a comment to a visualforce page?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use the XML comment syntax, which is:

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
```

Comment: With the caveat that it's valid for text-only comments, but won't always "comment out" code.

Comment: that will still appear in HTML response won't it? Is there a comment syntax which does not appear in the response at all?